# css not showing in coverage tab of google chrome

Tags: css, angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, code-coverage

I would like to analyse the amount of unused CSS on my webpage. This web page is written in Angular 7 and the css is being added in the angular.json build configuration.

This seems to be appending the css to the head of the html file; in the developer tools I can see several style tags.

I have read in many places that I should use the coverage tab of the developers tools in Google Chrome to do this. For me this is working for JS but not for CSS.

Here are screenshots of what I am seeing:

[image]

It is all JS. If I filter for files that conatin css it returns no results

[image]

But I can see that css files have been downloaded here.

[image]

How can I analyse the code coverage styles in the head of the document?

The head of my document looks like this:

[image]

[image]

p.s. I am using Chrome Version 75.0.3770.80 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Can you share the URL ? I've just updated Chrome and it works here. Also tried with success in https://brave.com/ you could give it a try, it's a Chrome "spin-off" browser.

Comment: I am using a local dev environment (IIS on windows). If I send you the same url that I am visiting it won't work.

Comment: Does it work on external sites ?

Comment: It works on stackoverflow

Comment: I am including the css file in angular.json

Comment: Tried it in Brave... same result

Comment: Is your app a Chrome extension ?

Comment: Can you paste the `<head>` part of the HTML of offending page ?

Comment: ```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>offending page</title>
  <script>window['__Zone_enable_cross_context_check'] = true;</script>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  <base href="/" />

</head>

```

Comment: I am using angular 7 and including css files from node_modules in the angular.json build configuration

Comment: Wait. hold the phone. When I look at the head element in the elements inspector of dev tools, there are a tonne of style tags

Comment: Edit the question and put that info.

Comment: In your pasted image it doesn't seem like you're serving the page from IIS.

Comment: how would you tell? I am going to update question now. thanks

Comment: The links on the image start with `chrome-extension://` and not something like `http://localhost`

Comment: smart man. but it's there. localhost is named something else

Comment: When you load the page with problems, does Console gets any error message ?

Comment: You didn't put the head tag HTML content in your question...

Comment: done now @Niloct thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So all your CSS is internal it seems (they're not being served from a file, are bundled in the HTML).

Do a small test: put the CSS content of one of the `<style>` tags in a `.css` file (for instance, `test.css`) and include those files in `<head>` with `<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">`, and see if they work, and show up in coverage.

(and remove the corresponding `<style>` tag from original)

**EDIT**

If you don't filter by keyword `CSS`, you will see that there is a single row with type `CSS+JS` or `JS`, which DOESN'T show when you filter by keyword `CSS`.

Since your styles are all bundled in the HTML, they all clobber up to this row!

For instance:

[image: CSS+JS in Coverage tab]

Your address would be the root URL of the application.

**EDIT**

https://codepen.io/nilo-c-sar-teixeira/full/KLjbZW

You were right regarding dynamic CSS, it just isn't covered in the tab. The above link puts a `<style>` tag via javascript and the rules never show in any rows of the coverage tab. Good job :)

Comment: I don't see this CSS+JS line you speak of

Comment: @JoeyGough the URL filter searches only in the URL text, so if you are loading an URL which doesn't have the text `css` on it, it won't be filtered. Perhaps the line that I highlighted shows with type `CSS` only for you there, since all your JS are on external files.

Comment: Look for the row that corresponds to the address that is presented in the browser address bar when you first access the application.

Comment: ok for me. that url is only showing JS and it is relatively tiny (400 bytes). The file, as it is downloaded, does not contain all the style tags (must be why it is only labeled js). Some JS must be appending the style tags in the dom during the initial render.